# Is there a way to write a lambda function that can select just some elements of an array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, string, lambda

For example, given the array a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"], I can print all of it using a lambda function like this

```
print((lambda x:x)(a))
```

but if I wanted to output just the even indexes, I could solve it using something like this

```
print([x for i,x in enumerate(a) if i%2==0])
```

my output

```
["one","three"]
```

but how can I have the same output using a lambda function?

Comment: any Python function can be written as a lambda, so the answer to your question is yes

Comment: @DaveKielpinski In the sense of the Church-Turing hypothesis, yes, but re-writing many Python functions as a lambda expression would render them unrecognizable.

Comment: @chepner that wasn't the question, though.

Comment: And your comment wasn't helpful in any meaningful way.

Comment: I rewrote the question exemplifying what I want to do. Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: (x == "one" or x =="three"), my_list))
print(result)
```

Basically the filter function filters out all the items of the list that return false in the lambda, so you could filter out anything by replacing the second part.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this with `operator.itemgetter`.

```
>>> a = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> itemgetter(0, 2)(a)
("one", "three")
```

`itemgetter` was one of the functions introduced when the lambda expression was being considered for removal from Python 3000 (the language that was eventually released as Python 3). It was intended to replace the need for `lambda` in an expression like

```
>>> (lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))(a)
("one", "three")
```

while also being slightly more efficient.